# Authentication Module Perl

Tags: perl, authentication

New to web development in Perl. Im searching for a perl module to handle user authentication in web site. Registration, login, session, password recovery. Im working in a project using HTML::Template.

Answer (score 2):

This is too complicated for one module to handle, as there are UI elements to consider, as well as back-end storage of the user credentials, etc.  This is handled by many web frameworks, of which I would recommend [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/).